# Node stops working

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to run a node of ROS.
When I tape the commande :

```
rosrun  ratslam_ros ratslam_Youness src/ratslam_ros/config/config_irataus.txt.in
```

The node stops working. And in the log file I get the error :

```
[ WARN] [1486130761.721137111]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
```

But the program still working
What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253726/node-stops-working/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error tells you exactly what the problem is

```
new node registered with same name
```

This means that you already have another instance of that same node running. When you start another instance the names collide and ROS Master kills the node you're trying to run. If you want to use this node twice, consider using a launch file and giving each instance a unique name.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2